# Simple sum of two numbers file i/o in F#, Haskell, Scala, and Visual Basic or other functional programming languages

Tags: vb.net, scala, haskell, f#, sum

I'm working on an online judge for algorithm contests. I want to include support for many programming languages, but i don't know all of them. I have to make test sources, but i don't know all of these languages.

I want the equivalent of this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int a, b;

    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    printf("%d", a + b);

    return 0;
}
```

In this programming languages.

I want to read from file input.txt two numbers, each on a line, and write the sum of them to the output file output.txt

Thank you.

**EDIT** Please don't tell me that Visual Basic .NET is not a functional language. I know it.

Comment: If you would comment what the code does it would be a bit easier.

Comment: When did Visual Basic become a functional programming language?

Comment: You can use LINQ, but I agree it doesn't count.

Comment: I don't really understand the motivation. File I/O isn't exactly the thing functional languages excel in...

Comment: Well, the input must be read from the file, and to be output to the file, this is the standard. Don't ask me why. There aren't only functional languages, I have already support for Ada, C, C++, D, Pascal, Python, Lua, Perl, Php, Ruby, Ocaml, C#, Boo, Tcl and Pike.

Comment: It's been a long while since I last used C, but are you sure that `scanf` will read numbers from two lines? Also, I'd focus on describing the input and output clearly and with examples. And note whether whitespace matters, if the input has to be tested for conformance, etc.

Comment: @belwood: you might want to take a look at http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1406

Comment: Maybe add the rosetta-stone tag?

Comment: Why not read/write to std IO?

Comment: "I'm working on an online judge for algorithm contest" -- are you judging the code or the output?

Comment: too bad all answers have taken the *golf* route.

Answer (score 9):

Haskell:

```
main = do
    [astr, bstr] <- fmap lines (readFile "input.txt")
    writeFile "output.txt" $ show (read astr + read bstr)
```

Or to sum all lines:

```
main = writeFile "output.txt" . show . sum . map read . lines =<< readFile "input.txt"
```

Comment: I think you need a `take 2` between `map read` and `lines` if I read the problem correctly.

Comment: @yatima2975, "or to sum all lines". Though that take 2 isn't a bad idea to clean up the first one.

Answer (score 5):

In F#:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllLines "input.txt" |> Seq.sumBy int |> string
|> fun s -> System.IO.File.WriteAllText("output.txt", s)
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a ton of ways of doing this in **Scala**.

```
val f = (as : Array[String]) => as(0).toInt + as(1).toInt
io.Source.fromFile("C:/myfile.xtx").getLines().toStream match {
  case line1 #:: _ => println(f(line1.split(","))
}
```

You could also do...

```
val splitLine = (_ : String).split(",")
val printSum = (as : Array[String]) => println(as(0).toInt + as(1).toInt)
val sums = io.Source.fromFile("C:/f.xtx").getLines() map (splitLine andThen printSum)
sums.head //start printing as Iterator is lazy
```

But then since side-effects should generally be avoided, you would probably want to make your functions *pure*

```
val sumLine = (as : Array[String]) => as(0).toInt + as(1).toInt
val sums = io.Source.fromFile("C:/f.xtx").getLines() map (splitLine andThen sumLine)
println(sums.head)
```

Comment: The numbers come each on a different line, not separated by commas. Which actually makes the first example even simpler. And if you go with some other assumptions that there are only two lines, it's even easier. On the ohter hand, you have to write the output to a file -- I assume the code will be automatically tested based on the output, like TopCoder does (though they capture stdout).

Answer (score 4):

An F# version that assumes that the input file contains just two lines (with numbers):

```
open System.IO

let [| astr; bstr |] = File.ReadAllLines "input.txt" 
File.WriteAllText("output.txt", string (int astr + int bstr))
```

This is a bit simpler than Jon's version, but it is a more direct solution (and behaves the same as Haskell solution posted by others).

Answer (score 4):

Some answers here seem confused about what the C code does.  The C code is not particularly useful.  It takes a file like

```
42
1776
this is any sort of random junk
because the program never reads this far
```

and produces a file containing

```
1818
```

and that is it.  IMO, this is a lousy example for showing the power of functional languages because it does so little--one instance of one operation, basically.  *Yawn*.  With about the same amount of work, you could take a file with two columns of numbers and produce a file that had their sum in one column as an output.  With a tiny bit more work, you could handle any conceivable error in the input.

But, fair enough, if this is the job at hand, one way to accomplish this in Scala is:

```
val pw = new java.io.PrintWriter("output.txt")
val num = scala.io.Source.fromFile("input.txt").getLines().map(_.toInt)
pw.print(num.next+num.next)
pw.close  // Only use this line if execution continues (e.g. in REPL)
```

Comment: I think it's not about showing the power of functional languages.  I think it's just a "starter kit" for a contest, and this guy didn't know those languages.

Comment: @luqui - I agree.  It's just strange that one would lump functional languages together in the question.  For a task like this, I'd go alphabetically.

Answer (score 3):

Racket Scheme:

```
(define (simpleSum)
  (let* ((input (map string->number (file->lines "input.txt")))
         (a (first input)) (b (second input)))
    (write-to-file (number->string (+ a b)) "output.txt")))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think scala has its advantage in such simple scenario, including all its fancy features and its api. It's better to use java library. java.util.Scanner has provided the useful nextInt() which can work in many cases and PrintWriter is the fastest output mechniasm in java.

`val in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("input.txt"))`

`val out = new PrintWriter("output.txt")`

`out.println((in.nextInt + in.nextInt))`

`out.close`

`in.close`

And also, I'm curious about which online judge you're working on :)

Comment: Well, it is not ready yet, i want to come with something new. I have the grader which is a standalone part, that can be used in both online and offline contests.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the VB.NET implementation:

```
Dim FileLines() as string = system.io.file.readalllines("input.txt")
system.io.file.WriteAllText("output.txt", ctype(FileLines(0), integer) + ctype(FileLines(1), integer))
```

Answer (score -4):

Visual Basic is not a functional language, unless you use some of the LINQ features.

Comment: I know it is not. Sorry for confusion, but the main languages I don't know are the functional ones like haskell and f#. Visual Basic was added after them.

Comment: How can using or not using some features of a language affect the fact whether the language is functional or not?